# How do I multiply two sparse matrices in C?

Tags: c, blas, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix D, and I want to multiply D_transpose and D to get L as follows:

L = D'*D;

I am using sparseBLAS to deal with sparse matrices, but the [documentation](http://www.cerfacs.fr/algor/reports/2001/TR_PA_01_24.pdf) says there's nothing to multiply two sparse matrices.

I am completely stuck and have no idea how to proceed.

The dimensions of D are typically around 500,000 by 250,000. I cannot assign that much memory at all, so it just has to be done using sparse matrices.

I did this using MATLAB, and I don't understand how MATLAB does it if it also uses sparseBLAS underneath the interface - or does it? If not, what does it use? I could use that too.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: Solved. I needed the L matrix to multiply with a vector. So instead of first calculating L, I simply did D'*(D*x), thus avoiding the need for multiplication of two sparse matrices. I now only do sparse matrix and dense vector multiplicatin, which is supported by sparseBLAS.

Comment: You could also invoke Matlab functions from your C application. Search for "Matlab Compiler Runtime".

Answer (score 2):

Intel's library MKL supports the product of two sparse matrices. You can check the routine `mkl_sparse_spmm` from the reference of MKL. (Old version of MKL used the routine `mkl_?csrmultcsr` which is deprecated now.)

Additionally, there is an old but widely used open-source and thread-safe sparse matrix library `SPARSKIT` (and its updated version `SPARSKIT2`). Both of them are written by F77. There is a routine `amub` that can be used to get the product of two sparse matrices. You can check is there anyone rewrite this library to C.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is stated in the documentation posted.

Page 11

> **5.2 Using Sparse BLAS matrices**
>
> Once a Sparse BLAS matrix handle has been completely constructed (something
>   that can be tested by checking the property blas_valid_handle), it is possible to
>   use the matrix handle to perform operations. **At this time the four operations shown
>   in Tables 3.2 and 3.3 are supported.**
>   In addition to performing operations with a Sparse BLAS matrix, it is possible
>   to query its properties through its handle. Table 5.5 lists the properties that can be
>   obtained by calling the get properties routine.

Table 3.3 Page 4

> USMM sparse matrix-matrix multiplication

So support seems to be there. I just can't find the signature for the `BLAS_usmm` function. Maybe you can check into the headers.

Edit: If you got your sparseBLas from [NIST](http://math.nist.gov/spblas/) you can check the `blas_sparse_proto.h` file for the `BLAS_*usmm` functions for the signatures and parameters.

```
 /* Level 3 Computational Routines */

int BLAS_susmm( enum blas_order_type order, enum blas_trans_type transa,
    int nrhs, float alpha, blas_sparse_matrix A, const float *b, int ldb,
        float *c, int ldc );
int BLAS_dusmm( enum blas_order_type order, enum blas_trans_type transa,
        int nrhs, double alpha, blas_sparse_matrix A, const double *b,
        int ldb, double *c, int ldc );
int BLAS_cusmm( enum blas_order_type order, enum blas_trans_type transa,
         int nrhs, const void *alpha, blas_sparse_matrix A, const void *b, 
     int ldb, void *c, int ldc );
int BLAS_zusmm( enum blas_order_type order, enum blas_trans_type transa,
         int nrhs, const void *alpha, blas_sparse_matrix A, const void *b, 
     int ldb, void *c, int ldc );
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was looking to multiply two sparse matrices, not one sparse matrix with a dense matrix. The functions you describe are for the latter case. I found out a way of circumventing this issue, though. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, your problem is mainly storing huge matrix in the memory. You can store the values in (row, column) pair. For example,

```
1 0 0
0 0 2
0 4 0
```

This matrix can be stored in a `std::map<pair<int, int>, int>` as:

```
map[make_pair(1, 1)] = 1
map[make_pair(2, 3)] = 2
map[make_pair(3, 2)] = 4
```

Now the computation part. Assuming that first matrix is stored in `map1`, second matrix is stored in `map2` and the answer is stored in `mapAns`,

```
for each element x in map1:
    for each element y in map2:
        if x.column == y.row:
            mapAns[x.row, y.column] += x.value * y.value
```

You need to use map like custom data structure if you want to do the same in C.

Comment: He is not asking about how to implement sparse matrices as he is already using a library which supports that.

Comment: The COO format is generally not efficient for big matrices. (Depending on the number of non-zero values)